# Iterador em Web Scraping pegando apenas elementos com index ímpares

Tags: python, web-scraping, iterator

estava fazendo WebScraping de uma página de venda de carros e por algum motivo ao iterar os dados para recolher os dados de Quilometragem rodada o iterador simplesmente repetia os itens, ou seja :
27000
27000
48000
48000
1000
1000

gostaria de saber como eu pego apenas os valores com index Ímpares em um iterador Python

```
soup = soup.find('div',class_="nm-features-container") 

for item in soup.findAll('div',class_="nm-features nm-km"):
    print(item.get_text().replace('\n','').replace(' ',''))
```

url = https://busca.autoline.com.br/comprar/carros/novos-seminovos-usados/todos-os-estados/todas-as-cidades/todas-as-marcas/todos-os-modelos/todas-as-versoes/todos-os-anos/todas-as-cores/todos-os-precos/

Comment: Importante você [edit] seu post e explicar detalhadamente a parte que está tendo problema, descrevendo o que tentou e onde está a dificuldade atual, de preferência com um [mcve]. Estudar a postagem disponível neste link pode fazer uma diferença muito positiva no seu aproveitamento do site: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você tem 2 divs com classe `nm-features-container` para cada elemento. O certo então seria você ser mais específico sobre qual div você quer. Olhando o HTML, tem um div que tem uma segunda classe (`nm-automaker-list-view`). Filtrando pelas 2, é possivel pegar apenas um elemento.

Exemplo de scraping:

```
import requests
import bs4

URL = 'https://busca.autoline.com.br/comprar/carros/novos-seminovos-usados/todos-os-estados/todas-as-cidades/todas-as-marcas/todos-os-modelos/todas-as-versoes/todos-os-anos/todas-as-cores/todos-os-precos/'

response = requests.get(URL)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.content)

containers = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': "nm-features-container nm-automaker-list-view"}) 
for container in containers:
    km = container.find('div', attrs={'class': 'nm-features nm-km '}).get_text().strip()
    city = container.find('div', attrs={'class': 'nm-city-tooltip'}).get_text().strip()

    print (km, city)
>> 27.000 Frederico Westphalen, RS
>> 50.000 Três Passos, RS
>> 120.000 Três Passos, RS
```